# Sync two SVG animations along different paths

Tags: animation, svg, synchronization

Hope I am explaining this correctly.
I have two pulse animations that are running along two different paths. I have played with the duration of the animations but I can seem to get them to "sync" at the point where they join so that only one circle goes to the top.
Is this possible?

Here is my code :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="300"
   height="300"
   viewBox="0 0 120 120"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg11"
   sodipodi:docname="testAn.svg"
   inkscape:version="0.92.5 (2060ec1f9f, 2020-04-08)">
  <metadata
     id="metadata17">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id="defs15" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="1600"
     inkscape:window-height="837"
     id="namedview13"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="2.4857496"
     inkscape:cx="201.80878"
     inkscape:cy="187.12268"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg11" />
  <g
     id="g140"
     transform="translate(35.662173,31.252367)">
    <path
       id="theMotionPath-sa"
       d="M 10,10 V 40 H 52"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#4789d0;stroke-width:1" />
    <circle
       id="circle119"
       r="2"
       cy="0"
       cx="0"
       style="fill:#4789d0">
      <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion
         keyTimes="0;1"
         calcMode="linear"
         keyPoints="1;0"
         repeatCount="indefinite"
         dur="3s"
         begin="0s">
        <mpath
           xlink:href="#theMotionPath-sa" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
    <circle
       id="circle121"
       r="2"
       cy="0"
       cx="0"
       style="fill:#4789d0">
      <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion
         keyTimes="0;1"
         calcMode="linear"
         keyPoints="1;0"
         repeatCount="indefinite"
         dur="3s"
         begin="1s">
        <mpath
           xlink:href="#theMotionPath-sa" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
    <circle
       id="circle123"
       r="2"
       cy="0"
       cx="0"
       style="fill:#4789d0">
      <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion
         keyTimes="0;1"
         calcMode="linear"
         keyPoints="1;0"
         repeatCount="indefinite"
         dur="3s"
         begin="2s">
        <mpath
           xlink:href="#theMotionPath-sa" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
    <circle
       id="circle125"
       r="2"
       cy="0"
       cx="0"
       style="fill:#4789d0">
      <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion
         keyTimes="0;1"
         calcMode="linear"
         keyPoints="1;0"
         repeatCount="indefinite"
         dur="3s"
         begin="3s">
        <mpath
           xlink:href="#theMotionPath-sa" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
  </g>
  <g
     id="g57"
     transform="translate(15.662173,36.252367)">
    <path
       id="theMotionPath-ch"
       d="M 10,35 H 30 V 3"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#4789d0;stroke-width:1" />
    <circle
       id="circle36"
       r="2"
       cy="0"
       cx="0"
       style="fill:#4789d0">
      <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion
         keyTimes="0;1"
         calcMode="linear"
         keyPoints="0;1"
         repeatCount="indefinite"
         dur="3s"
         begin="0s">
        <mpath
           xlink:href="#theMotionPath-ch" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
    <circle
       id="circle38"
       r="2"
       cy="0"
       cx="0"
       style="fill:#4789d0">
      <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion
         keyTimes="0;1"
         calcMode="linear"
         keyPoints="0;1"
         repeatCount="indefinite"
         dur="3s"
         begin="1s">
        <mpath
           xlink:href="#theMotionPath-ch" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
    <circle
       id="circle40"
       r="2"
       cy="0"
       cx="0"
       style="fill:#4789d0">
      <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion
         keyTimes="0;1"
         calcMode="linear"
         keyPoints="0;1"
         repeatCount="indefinite"
         dur="3s"
         begin="2s">
        <mpath
           xlink:href="#theMotionPath-ch" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
    <circle
       id="circle42"
       r="2"
       cy="0"
       cx="0"
       style="fill:#4789d0">
      <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion
         keyTimes="0;1"
         calcMode="linear"
         keyPoints="0;1"
         repeatCount="indefinite"
         dur="3s"
         begin="3s">
        <mpath
           xlink:href="#theMotionPath-ch" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just building from @ccprog's answer, you can also use `keyTimes` and `keyPoints` to change the speed of the animation in the horizontal and vertical parts. You need to realise a couple of things:

- First, you need to `#theMotionPath-ch`'s `d` attribute to `d="M 10,35 H 30 V 5"`, so that it gets to the same vertical point as the other path
- Then, calculate the point where each path changes relative to its length: 0.4167 in `#theMotionPath-sa` and 0.4 in `#theMotionPath-ch`.
- Finally, add an additional `keyTime` (I set it at `0.6`, meaning at the `0.6 * 3s = 1.8s` and the corresponding `keyPoint` from the previous step.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="300"
   height="300"
   viewBox="0 0 120 120"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg11"
   sodipodi:docname="testAn.svg"
   inkscape:version="0.92.5 (2060ec1f9f, 2020-04-08)">
  <metadata
     id="metadata17">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id="defs15" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="1600"
     inkscape:window-height="837"
     id="namedview13"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="2.4857496"
     inkscape:cx="201.80878"
     inkscape:cy="187.12268"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg11" />
  <g
     id="g140"
     transform="translate(35.662173,31.252367)">
    <path
       id="theMotionPath-sa"
       d="M 10,10 V 40 H 52"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#4789d0;stroke-width:1" />
    <circle
       id="circle119"
       r="2"
       cy="0"
       cx="0"
       style="fill:#4789d0">
      <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion
         keyTimes="0;0.6;1"
         calcMode="linear"
         keyPoints="1;0.4167;0"
         repeatCount="indefinite"
         dur="3s"
         begin="0s">
        <mpath
           xlink:href="#theMotionPath-sa" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
    <circle
       id="circle121"
       r="2"
       cy="0"
       cx="0"
       style="fill:#4789d0">
      <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion
         keyTimes="0;0.6;1"
         calcMode="linear"
         keyPoints="1;0.4167;0"
         repeatCount="indefinite"
         dur="3s"
         begin="1s">
        <mpath
           xlink:href="#theMotionPath-sa" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
    <circle
       id="circle123"
       r="2"
       cy="0"
       cx="0"
       style="fill:#4789d0">
      <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion
         keyTimes="0;0.6;1"
         calcMode="linear"
         keyPoints="1;0.4167;0"
         repeatCount="indefinite"
         dur="3s"
         begin="2s">
        <mpath
           xlink:href="#theMotionPath-sa" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
    <circle
       id="circle125"
       r="2"
       cy="0"
       cx="0"
       style="fill:#4789d0">
      <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion
         keyTimes="0;0.6;1"
         calcMode="linear"
         keyPoints="1;0.4167;0"
         repeatCount="indefinite"
         dur="3s"
         begin="3s">
        <mpath
           xlink:href="#theMotionPath-sa" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
  </g>
  <g
     id="g57"
     transform="translate(15.662173,36.252367)">
    <path
       id="theMotionPath-ch"
       d="M 10,35 H 30 V 5"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#4789d0;stroke-width:1" />
    <circle
       id="circle36"
       r="2"
       cy="0"
       cx="0"
       style="fill:#4789d0">
      <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion
         keyTimes="0;0.6;1"
         calcMode="linear"
         keyPoints="0;0.40;1"
         repeatCount="indefinite"
         dur="3s"
         begin="0s">
        <mpath
           xlink:href="#theMotionPath-ch" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
    <circle
       id="circle38"
       r="2"
       cy="0"
       cx="0"
       style="fill:#4789d0">
      <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion
         keyTimes="0;0.6;1"
         calcMode="linear"
         keyPoints="0;0.40;1"
         repeatCount="indefinite"
         dur="3s"
         begin="1s">
        <mpath
           xlink:href="#theMotionPath-ch" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
    <circle
       id="circle40"
       r="2"
       cy="0"
       cx="0"
       style="fill:#4789d0">
      <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion
         keyTimes="0;0.6;1"
         calcMode="linear"
         keyPoints="0;0.40;1"
         repeatCount="indefinite"
         dur="3s"
         begin="2s">
        <mpath
           xlink:href="#theMotionPath-ch" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
    <circle
       id="circle42"
       r="2"
       cy="0"
       cx="0"
       style="fill:#4789d0">
      <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion
         keyTimes="0;0.6;1"
         calcMode="linear"
         keyPoints="0;0.40;1"
         repeatCount="indefinite"
         dur="3s"
         begin="3s">
        <mpath
           xlink:href="#theMotionPath-ch" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

After Looking at the examples it occurred to me that as long as the time of each animation stays the same and the interval at witch each animation run also stays the same then the lengths of the paths would not make any difference. All that will change is the speed of the animation.

Here is another exsample:

```html
<svg width="300" height="300"  viewBox="0 0 120 120"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >

    
   <!-- Edit This Path .   -->  
    <path d="M 10,60 H 60 "    stroke="#4789D0"  stroke-width="1"  fill="none" id="M-Right"/>
    <path d="M 60,60 v -50 "    stroke="#4789D0"  stroke-width="1"  fill="none" id="M-Up"/>
    <path d="M 60,60 h 30"    stroke="#4789D0"  stroke-width="1"  fill="none" id="M-Left"/>
   <!-- Here is a green circle which will be moved along the motion path. -->
   <circle cx="" cy="" r="2" fill="#4789D0" >
         <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion id="c1" begin='0s' dur='3s' repeatCount="indefinite"  keyPoints="0;1" calcMode="linear" keyTimes="0;1"> <mpath xlink:href="#M-Right"/> </animateMotion>
    </circle>
    
       <circle cx="" cy="" r="2" fill="#4789D0" >
         <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion id="c2" begin='1s' dur='3s' repeatCount="indefinite"  keyPoints="0;1" calcMode="linear" keyTimes="0;1"> <mpath xlink:href="#M-Right"/> </animateMotion>
    </circle>

       <circle cx="" cy="" r="2" fill="#4789D0" >
         <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion id="c3" begin='2s' dur='3s' repeatCount="indefinite"  keyPoints="0;1" calcMode="linear" keyTimes="0;1"> <mpath xlink:href="#M-Right"/> </animateMotion>
    </circle>
        
       <circle cx="" cy="" r="2" fill="#4789D0" >
         <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion id="c4" begin='3s' dur='3s' repeatCount="indefinite"  keyPoints="0;1" calcMode="linear" keyTimes="0;1"> <mpath xlink:href="#M-Right"/> </animateMotion>
    </circle>  
  
 <circle cx="" cy="" r="2" fill="#4789D0" >
         <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion id="vc1"  begin='c1.begin+3s' dur='3s' repeatCount="indefinite" keyPoints="0;1" calcMode="linear" keyTimes="0;1"> <mpath xlink:href="#M-Up"/> </animateMotion>
    </circle>
    
 <circle cx="" cy="" r="2" fill="#4789D0" >
         <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion id="vc2"  begin='c2.begin+3s' dur='3s' repeatCount="indefinite" keyPoints="0;1" calcMode="linear" keyTimes="0;1"> <mpath xlink:href="#M-Up"/> </animateMotion>
    </circle>   
    
 <circle cx="" cy="" r="2" fill="#4789D0" >
         <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion id="vc3"  begin='c3.begin+3s' dur='3s' repeatCount="indefinite" keyPoints="0;1" calcMode="linear" keyTimes="0;1"> <mpath xlink:href="#M-Up"/> </animateMotion>
    </circle>

 <circle cx="" cy="" r="2" fill="#4789D0" >
         <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion id="vc4"  begin='c4.begin+3s' dur='3s' repeatCount="indefinite" keyPoints="0;1" calcMode="linear" keyTimes="0;1"> <mpath xlink:href="#M-Up"/> </animateMotion>
    </circle>


<circle cx="" cy="" r="2" fill="#4789D0" >
         <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion id="lc1"  begin='c1.begin+0s' dur='3s' repeatCount="indefinite" keyPoints="1;0" calcMode="linear" keyTimes="0;1"> <mpath xlink:href="#M-Left"/> </animateMotion>
    </circle>
    
<circle cx="" cy="" r="2" fill="#4789D0" >
         <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion id="lc2"  begin='c2.begin+0s' dur='3s' repeatCount="indefinite" keyPoints="1;0" calcMode="linear" keyTimes="0;1"> <mpath xlink:href="#M-Left"/> </animateMotion>
    </circle>
<circle cx="" cy="" r="2" fill="#4789D0" >
         <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion id="lc3"  begin='c3.begin+0s' dur='3s' repeatCount="indefinite" keyPoints="1;0" calcMode="linear" keyTimes="0;1"> <mpath xlink:href="#M-Left"/> </animateMotion>
    </circle>
<circle cx="" cy="" r="2" fill="#4789D0" >
         <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
      <animateMotion id="lc4"  begin='c4.begin+0s' dur='3s' repeatCount="indefinite" keyPoints="1;0" calcMode="linear" keyTimes="0;1"> <mpath xlink:href="#M-Left"/> </animateMotion>
    </circle>
                
    
    
</svg>
```

You can edit the length but it will still stay in sync

Answer (score 4):

Your main problem is that your dots are moving at different speeds, because the motion paths have different lengths. I think the most sensible solution is to define **three** separate motion paths, one for the left and right leg, and one for the upward leg. Then, time your animations such that the animations *end* at the central point at the same time for the left and right leg, and that they *start* at that same time for the upward leg.

This requires carefull planing of motion speeds and timing, and implicitely knowledge about path lengths. To make it easier to follow the reasoning, I've resolved the transforms from your SVG and repositioned and resized the paths a bit. Also, I have reversed the direction of the right leg so that you do not need to reverse the direction of the motion - sparing you to spell out the `keyPoints`/`keyTimes` attributes.

Here is what I got:

```
id                   d              length   dur
theMotionPath-left   M 25 70 H 45   20       1.5s
theMotionPath-right  M 85 70 H 45   40       3s
theMotionPath-up     M 45 70 V 40   30       2s
```

The speeds in the different legs do match up perfectly, only approximately. But that is no deterrent, all that matters is that all dots reach/leave the central point on every full second.

The left leg has a problem, though. `repeatCount="indefinite"` means that the animation restarts immediately after finishing. A motion starting at 1.5s would end at 3s, then again after 4.5s, 6s, 7.5s,... Every second motion would *not* match up with the other parts as required.

What would solve this is an additional **delay** between each animation start: run for 1.5s, wait for 1.5s, run again etc.

This can be done with a trick. It is possible to [bind the start of an animation to the end of another animation](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html#SyncbaseValueSyntax) - or to a different run of the same animation. Leave out the `repeatCount` attribute, but define a *list* of `begin` times:

```
      <animateMotion id="leftDot1" dur="1.5s" begin="1.5s;leftDot1.end + 1.5s">
        <mpath xlink:href="#theMotionPath-left" />
      </animateMotion>
```

After 1.5s, the animation is started for the first time, and additionally each time the animation with the id `leftDot1` (which is itself) ends, it waits for 1.5s and then starts again.

```html
<svg width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 120 120"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <g>
    <path id="theMotionPath-left" d="M 25 70 H 45"
          style="fill:none;stroke:#4789d0;stroke-width:1" />
    <circle r="2" cy="0" cx="0" style="fill:#4789d0">
      <animateMotion id="leftDot1" dur="1.5s" begin="1.5s;leftDot1.end + 1.5s">
        <mpath xlink:href="#theMotionPath-left" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
    <circle r="2" cy="0" cx="0" style="fill:#4789d0">
      <animateMotion id="leftDot2" dur="1.5s" begin="2.5s;leftDot2.end + 1.5s">
        <mpath xlink:href="#theMotionPath-left" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
    <circle r="2" cy="0" cx="0" style="fill:#4789d0">
      <animateMotion id="leftDot3" dur="1.5s" begin="3.5s;leftDot3.end + 1.5s">
        <mpath xlink:href="#theMotionPath-left" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path id="theMotionPath-right" d="M 85 70 H 45"
          style="fill:none;stroke:#4789d0;stroke-width:1" />
    <circle r="2" cy="0" cx="0" style="fill:#4789d0">
      <animateMotion repeatCount="indefinite" dur="3s" begin="0s">
        <mpath xlink:href="#theMotionPath-right" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
    <circle r="2" cy="0" cx="0" style="fill:#4789d0">
      <animateMotion repeatCount="indefinite" dur="3s" begin="1s">
        <mpath xlink:href="#theMotionPath-right" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
    <circle r="2" cy="0" cx="0" style="fill:#4789d0">
      <animateMotion repeatCount="indefinite" dur="3s" begin="2s">
        <mpath xlink:href="#theMotionPath-right" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path id="theMotionPath-up" d="M 45 70 V 40"
          style="fill:none;stroke:#4789d0;stroke-width:1" />
    <circle r="2" cy="0" cx="0" style="fill:#4789d0">
      <animateMotion repeatCount="indefinite" dur="2s" begin="3s">
        <mpath xlink:href="#theMotionPath-up" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
    <circle r="2" cy="0" cx="0" style="fill:#4789d0">
      <animateMotion repeatCount="indefinite" dur="2s" begin="4s">
        <mpath xlink:href="#theMotionPath-up" />
      </animateMotion>
    </circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```